# How would I return a list that takes two lists and associates them with the contents in that list together in plait language for Racket?

Tags: racket, plai

I'm working on a problem that has me using Racket with plait language and I'm trying to get a program that takes two lists and associate them together like this. I am relatively new to Racket and the plait language.

```
'(a b c d) and '(1 2 3 4)
```

Together they should output:

```
'((make-assoc 'a 1) (make-assoc 'b 2) (make-assoc 'c 3) (make-assoc 'd 4)))
```

This is what I have defined so far:

```
#lang plait
(define-type Associate
  (assoc [name : Symbol]
         [values : Number]))

(define (make-assoc [names : (Listof Symbol)] [values : (Listof Number)]): (Listof assoc)
  (map (lambda (name value) (assoc name value)) names values))

(test (make-assoc '(a b c d) '(1 2 3 4))
      '((make-assoc 'a 1) (make-assoc 'b 2) (make-assoc 'c 3) (make-assoc 'd 4)))
(test (make-assoc '(t a c o tuesday) '(0 1 34 1729 42))
      '((make-assoc 't 0) (make-assoc 'a 1) (make-assoc 'c 34) (make-assoc 'o 1729) (make-assoc 'tuesday 42)))
```

I tried to get somewhere coming up stuff for make-assoc but I am having trouble with syntax and I guess I can't use map or lambda because make-assoc is already the identifier. So maybe I could use append in some way?

Comment: Could you add the exact instructions? Which definitions are included in the instructions and which are yours?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the type is `Associate`, not `assoc`.
`assoc` is the name of its only variant, and is used to construct values of the `Associate` type.

```
> assoc
- (Symbol Number -> Associate)
#<procedure:assoc>
> (assoc 'hello 1234)
- Associate
(assoc 'hello 1234)
```

So you should have

```
(define (make-associate [names : (Listof Symbol)] [values : (Listof Number)]): (Listof Associate)
...
```

(You also need to rename it, as `make-assoc` is already taken by the "machinery".)

Second, the type of `map` is

```
(('a -> 'b) (Listof 'a) -> (Listof 'b))
```

so it takes a *one*-argument function and *one* list and produces a list.
You want `map2`, which has the type

```
(('a 'b -> 'c) (Listof 'a) (Listof 'b) -> (Listof 'c))
```

So,

```
(define (make-associate [names : (Listof Symbol)] [values : (Listof Number)]): (Listof Associate)
  (map2 (lambda (name value) (assoc name value)) names values))
```

Third, quoting "suspends" evaluation; `'(a b)` is *not* the same as `(list a b)` – the former is a list of the *symbols* `a` and `b` while the latter is a list of the *values* those symbols are bound to.

```
> (define a 1)
> a
- Number
1
> 'a
- Symbol
'a
> (list a)
- (Listof Number)
'(1)
> '(a)
- (Listof Symbol)
'(a)
```

So you want to use `list` rather than `'` in your test cases.
You also use `assoc`, not `make-assoc`, to create values of the `Associate` type.

In summary:

```
(test (make-associate '(a b c d) '(1 2 3 4))
      (list (assoc 'a 1)
            (assoc 'b 2)
            (assoc 'c 3)
            (assoc 'd 4)))
(test (make-associate '(t a c o tuesday) '(0 1 34 1729 42))
      (list (assoc 't 0)
            (assoc 'a 1)
            (assoc 'c 34)
            (assoc 'o 1729)
            (assoc 'tuesday 42)))
```

And now,

```
good (make-associate '(a b c d) '(1 2 3 4)) at line 10
  expected: (list (assoc 'a 1) (assoc 'b 2) (assoc 'c 3) (assoc 'd 4))
  given: (list (assoc 'a 1) (assoc 'b 2) (assoc 'c 3) (assoc 'd 4))

good (make-associate '(t a c o tuesday) '(0 1 34 1729 42)) at line 14
  expected: (list (assoc 't 0) (assoc 'a 1) (assoc 'c 34) (assoc 'o 1729) (assoc 'tuesday 42))
  given: (list (assoc 't 0) (assoc 'a 1) (assoc 'c 34) (assoc 'o 1729) (assoc 'tuesday 42))
```